# What is the current approach to getting a Graphx graph from Neo4j?

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, spark-graphx, scala-spark

I understand that the previous (now [deprecated](https://neo4j.com/developer/apache-spark/)) Neo4j Spark Connector allowed for the generation of Spark Graphs and GraphFrames using the corresponding methods of the org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j class. With the Neo4j class gone, the only examples I found using the [new approach](https://neo4j.com/developer/spark/reading/) generate DataFrames based on something like:

```
spark.read.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")
    .option("url", "bolt://localhost:7687")
    .option("query", "...")
    .load()
```

How do I get Graph instances directly using the "Neo4j Connector for Apache Spark v4.0.0"?

Comment: I think that you will need to read graph nodes (via `labels` configuration) separately from edges (via `relationship` configuration), and then combine everything into a graphframe or graphx instance...

Comment: Thanks, @AlexOtt, sounds like quite an unfortunate step backwards, though, in terms of API functionality

Comment: Yeah, I didn’t dig into the new connector yet...